# Ionic/Angular2 - Inserting a "mediator" between Page.ts and Provider.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to know if its possible or at least a direction on:
Put a "mediator" file between my Home.ts and my Provider.ts.

For example:
On my Home.ts I'll call a `getJson()` method that will call my Mediator `getJson()` method that will call my Provider `getJson()` method.

The reason is, that think its a nice aproach to make treatmens and refines on the data I'm receiving.

Here is what I tried with extreme failure and frustrations.... :'(

**Home.ts**

```
ionViewDidLoad(){

   let observer: any = this.mediator.get().subscribe(
      (response: any) => this.get_success(response),
      (response: any) => this.get_fail(response));

}

private get_success(response: any): void {
   console.log('Sucess!', response)
}

private get_fail(response: any): void {
   console.log('Fail!', response)
}
```

**HomeMediator.ts**

```
get(): Observable<any>{
   let observer = this.dataService.get();

   observer.subscribe(
      (response: any) => this.get_success(response),
      (response: any) => this.get_fail(response));

   return observer;
}

get_success(res: Object){
   res['key'] = "VALOR";
   console.log('Ok!', res)
}

get_fail(res: any){
   console.log('Nops', res)
}
```

**Provider.ts**

```
public get(): Observable<Object> {
   return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());

}
```

**JSON File**

```
{
   "key": "value :D"
}
```

Any help? I don't necessarily need to use Observables.. I'm still in learning on Angular and Ionic... Thanks for any help guys! o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subscribing twice on an `Observable` which is **probably** why your code is failing. This shouldn't be done. I'll provide an alternative with callbacks. I won't add in your `Provider.ts` since that code is fine.

---

**Mediator**

```
// add two paramter callbacks
get(successCallback, errorCallback): void {
  this.dataService.get().subscribe(
     response => { 
       this.get_success(response);
       // execute the callback function AFTER this.get_success is finished
       successCallback(response);
     }, error => {
       this.get_fail(error);
       errorCallback(error);
     }
  );
}
```

**Home**

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

  // pass the functions to the mediator (without () )
  this.mediator.get(success, failure);
}

success(response: any) { /* some code */}
failure(error: any) { /* some code */}
```

---

Comment: You're a Saint who came down from Heaven just to elucidate me... 
You don't know how much you helped me, even if my problem isn't the correct or better aproach to do this!! 

T-H-A-N-K    Y-O-U!!!!